# How to describe the "opposite" side of upper triangle of a square matrix

Tags: matrices

When you say *upper triangle* of a square matrix, this refers to the side above the main diagonal of the matrix (putting aside whether that includes or excludes the diagonal). How would I refer to the "opposite" side of upper triangle? That is, if I draw the $y=x$ line and the side above that line?

I have a heat map (which is square) and I want to refer to the top triangle above the $y=x$ line but not sure how to describe concisely.

Comment: You could talk about the upper triangle of your n by n matrix after it has its columns flipped (ie the $ith$ column goes to the $(n - i)th$ column). But maybe there is a better way to say what you want to say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this the upper left triangle. The most important thing is for your readers to understand what you want to say, and you can always define the term in the text once and for all.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to call it top left triangle.